# Is there any way of wrapping the following text nodes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="WishListMember_LoginMergeCode">
Killer Idea
<br>
Outsource Course
<br>
App Development
<br>
</div>
```

I would like to turn that into this:

```
<div class="WishListMember_LoginMergeCode">
<a href="link1">Killer Idea</a>
<br>
<a href="link2">Outsource Course</a>
<br>
<a href="link3">App Development</a>
<br>
</div>
```

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Post the html instead of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.WishListMember_LoginMergeCode').contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wjS6F/

Update:

```
$('div').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap(function(index) {
   return '<a href="link'+ ++index +'"></a>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8P2gf/

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention that each link is different.

Comment: @alexchenco where is the link definitions

Comment: @Arun P Johny  Sorry what are the link definitions?

Comment: @alexchenco how do you know which text has to be linked to which linke